# Possible to pass multiple level data array using the data field of jQuery $.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

How do I pass multiple level array using jQuery ajax function?

Example of data to be passed:

```
{"data": { "username" : "name1" , "password" : "password1" } }
```

in

```
bodyContent = $.ajax({
      url: "somepage",
      global: false,
      type: "POST",
      **data:** ,
      ...
```

Comment: (passing single level data in JSON format works)

Comment: the back-end .cs file can catch this:
{ "username" : "name1" , "password" : "password1" } 

but for multiple levels
{"data": { "username" : "name1" , "password" : "password1" } }
Does not catch the children of "data" using something like
ctr.data.username

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)

```
var params = {
    "data": {
        "username" : "name1" ,
        "password" : "password1" 
    } 
};
    var str = jQuery.param(params);
    // decodeURIComponent(str) == data[username]=name1&data[password]=password1​
```

[here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JBcZW/)

Comment: nice demo. now I actually know what the back-end is expecting from your commented bit.

Answer (score 1):

[Encode](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/data/json_encode.php) it as a JSON string.

Comment: isn't it already in JSON ?

{"data": { "username" : "name1" , "password" : "password1" } }

Comment: @Brandon: No, if you pass in an object { "a" : "b" }, by default it gets form-encoded if the request is POST, and url-encoded if the request is a GET

Comment: @Brandon - currently it's just a JavaScript object; you have to encode it to JavaScript Object Notation.

Comment: thanks for explaining! you are right... Reigel gave a direct answer for your explanation :)